# Google Assistant Invalid response from webhook: Failed to translate JSON to ExecuteHttpResponse

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, actions-builder, google-assistant

First off, I'm new to Google Assistant so I have very little idea about what I am doing. I am trying to make a webhook request with the code below in an external js file on a webserver:

```
// Project Requirements
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Constructor
const app = conversation();

// Search Function
app.handle('contacctSearch', async conv => {

// Get Intent Parameters
const query = $session.params.contactName.original;
const pageType = $session.params.pageType.original;
if (pageType.toUpperCase() == 'WHITE PAGES') {
    const res = await fetch(`https://www.findyello.com/barbados/white-pages/?search=${query}`);
    console.log(res);
    // Parse res into text
    const text = res;
    conv.add(`Here is your first result. ${text}`);
} 

else if (pageType.toUpperCase() =='YELLOW PAGES') {
    const res = await fetch(`https://www.findyello.com/barbados/?search=${query}`);
    console.log(res);
    // Parse res into text
    const text = res;
    conv.add(`Here is your first result. ${text}`);
} 

else if (pageType.toUpperCase() =='GOVERNMENT PAGES') {
    const res = await fetch(`https://www.findyello.com/barbados/government/?search=${query}`);
    console.log(res);
    // Parse res into text
    const text = res;
    conv.add(`Here is your first result. ${text}`);
}
});
```

But, I am receiving an error: Invalid response from webhook: Failed to translate JSON to ExecuteHttpResponse..

```
{
"responseJson": "// console.log('Working!');\r\n\r\n// Project Requirements\r\nconst { conversation } 
= require('@assistant/conversation');\r\nconst functions = require('firebase-functions');\r\n\r\n// 
Constructor\r\nconst app = conversation();\r\n\r\n// Search Function\r\napp.handle('contacctSearch', 
async conv => {\r\n\r\n    // Get Intent Parameters\r\n    const query = 
$session.params.contactName.original;\r\n    const pageType = $session.params.pageType.original;\r\n    
if (pageType.toUpperCase() == 'WHITE PAGES') {\r\n        const res = await 
fetch(`https://www.findyello.com/barbados/white-pages/?search=${query}`);\r\n        
console.log(res);\r\n        // Parse res into text\r\n        const text = res;\r\n        
conv.add(`Here is your first result. ${text}`);\r\n    } \r\n    \r\n    else if 
(pageType.toUpperCase() =='YELLOW PAGES') {\r\n        const res = await 
fetch(`https://www.findyello.com/barbados/?search=${query}`);\r\n        console.log(res);\r\n        
// Parse res into text\r\n        const text = res;\r\n        conv.add(`Here is your first result. 
${text}`);\r\n    } \r\n    \r\n    else if (pageType.toUpperCase() =='GOVERNMENT PAGES') {\r\n        
const res = await fetch(`https://www.findyello.com/barbados/government/?search=${query}`);\r\n        
console.log(res);\r\n        // Parse res into text\r\n        const text = res;\r\n        
conv.add(`Here is your first result. ${text}`);\r\n    }\r\n    });\r\n"
}
```

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Is this your entire file? What is the filename?

Comment: @NickFelker Yes, this is my entire file and I have it linked to https://simplifiedapps.co/ga_barbados/js/google-assistant-updated-contact-search.js. Not sure why it isn't working at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your file is not being understood as code, but rather a plain text file. There are several things to change:

1. Be sure to [declare a Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#add-the-makeuppercase-function) at the bottom of your file:

```js
app.handle('contacctSearch', async conv => {
  // ...
})

exports.fulfillment = app
```

2. It seems like you're pointing your webhook to your textfile rather than ensuring it is available as something executable. You should make sure you [deploy your function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#deploy-functions-to-a-production-environment), which you're using Firebase Functions, then use the webhook URL that Firebase gives you:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

It will be a function in the format, with your project's ID:

```
https://us-central1-MY_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/fulfillment
```